# Git branch editing flag

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, gitlab

Is there an oportunity to put some sort of flag like "USERNAME is editing this branch" to git's branch? 
Such feature can help to show contributors which branch is not editing at this moment and they can feel free to put their flag like "MY_NAME is editing..." and make changes. It will reduce merging inside one branch and prevent two coders from editing one branch at the same time.

Is there product with such feature? GitHub Private Repositories, GitHub Enterprise, GitLab, GitLab EE, Bitbucket?

Comment: Not a good idea, but I've seen people stuck in the clearcase way of thinking push tags to the remote repo to communicate to other developers that they are "working on a branch"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer:

Gitlab, for example, have feature to mark merge request (branch) as *"Work in progress"* (WIP). So, any developer can see it in web interface and know who particularly is working on branch.

Answer (score 0):

"Reserving" a branch in such a way sort of goes against the way git is supposed to work. That being said, if I were you I would have each developer make their own branch (say, with their name in it) that only they are allowed to edit. Then the only merge they will have to do is when they merge their "private" branch into the main one.

Comment: I don't mean this. For example, we have branch for feature. Two developers just want to know if one of them is editing now files of this branch. This is only in purpose not to edit same files of this branch at the same time.